# Vertex shader to create and animate geometry in QQuickItem

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm reading through the comments on this Qt bug report:

https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-32741

That bug report suggests using a vertex shader with the `QSGGeometry` and animating in C++. I know the QML side supports shaders, but how do you access a shader from a `QSGGeometry` material that is handled via a C++ subclass of `QQuickItem` (as I interpret the bug report to suggest)? The vertex shaders accessed within QML are generally for deforming existing geometry, not really for creating new geometry or animating geometry, from what I can tell.

Or is the report suggesting to bypass QML completely for this task?

It would be pretty cool to pass data to a vertex shader for raw drawing and have the GL viewport be the Quick Item, but I don't think the QML shaders are designed for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your subclass of `QQuickItem` override `updatePaintNode()` method should create (and update when needed) instance of `QSGGeometryNode` and set it up with a `QSGGeometry` configured for specific geometry type. That will allow you to directly control Vertex Buffer Object (just one, but with arbitrary layout of vertex attributes) and use your custom shaders.

See "Custom Geometry" [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-customgeometry-example.html) in qt documentation. Full project is in official [repository](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative/source/examples/quick/scenegraph/customgeometry).

Even more interesting example is ["Texture in SGNode"](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative/source/examples/quick/scenegraph/textureinsgnode). It uses `QQuickWindow::beforeRendering()` signal to be able to run completely arbitrary OpenGL code. In this example custom rendering goes to Frame Buffer Object. Later this FBO is used as texture in a `QSGSimpleTextureNode` subclass.

Comment: it would appear that the API for QSGGeometry is not quite the same as the OpenGL drawing API, is that correct? I can't find info on the actual API and figure out how to use it, is that a common drawing toolset? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qsggeometrynode.html

Comment: `QSGGeometry` is an abstraction to work with VBOs. Drawing done with vertex and fragment shaders.